# Building a dynamic query with separate hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, searchkick

Ok, I've been trying to figure out how to approach this all morning. Let's say you have a hash that looks like this:

```
{"luxury_shopper"=>"10", "movie_goer"=>"80"}
```

and you want to build a query that looks like this:

```
Observation.search("something", boost_by: {biz_trv:{factor: 10}} && {day_com:{factor:100}})
```

My approach so far is to convert the incoming hash to look like this:

```
[{:luxury_shopper=>{:factor=>"10"}}, {:movie_goer=>{:factor=>"80"}}]
```

by iterating over the original hash like this:

```
params[:filter].map {|k,v| {k.to_sym => {factor:v}}}
```

The problem I'm having is that since the query I'm trying to build is made up of an unknown number of hashes that I will "boost_by", I can't just do something like `filters[0] && filters[1]` I'm stumped here. Does anyone know how I could dynamically insert hashes into my query and place the operator between them?

EDIT:

The query looks like this:

```
Observation.search("someting", boost_by: `insert hash` `insert operator` `insert hash` etc...)
```

The above query could have any number of hashes and operators. So if a user wanted to pass in 10 fields to boost_by, I need to be able to accept all 10 of those hashes and whatever operator goes between them, so for example, my query could look like either of the below examples:

```
Observation.search("something", boost_by: {biz_trv:{factor: 10}})

Observation.search("something", boost_by: {biz_trv:{factor: 12}} && {day_com:{factor:50}} && {location:{factor:40}})
```

Comment: it sounds like you just need one more step to go from your converted hash to an && of filters. Don't try and get fancy, just make it work :)

Comment: Please provide the output expected. I am not that familiar with `searchkick` but there are many users on here that can certainly help with `Hash` manipulation if you specify input and output.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky. The output needs to look like the example above `Observation.search("something", boost_by: {biz_trv:{factor: 10}} && {day_com:{factor:100}})`. The dynamic part is the part after `boost_by:`. That search produces a list of search kick results, and information about the quality of the results and other things that aren't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have a solution that involves forming a string of your query, and then using the #send method to deliver your query string to the object.

```
hash = {"luxury_shopper"=>"10", "movie_goer"=>"80"}
BLANK_PARAMS = "boost_by: "
params = BLANK_PARAMS
hash.each do |k, v|
  if params == BLANK_PARAMS
    params += "{#{k}: {factor: #{v}}}"
  else
    params += " && {#{k}: {factor: #{v}}}"
  end
end
```

at the end of this operation, the params string will be the following:

```
"boost_by: {luxury_shopper: {factor: 10}} && {movie_goer: { factor: 80}}"
```

so if you now wanted to run the following command:

```
Observation.search("something", boost_by: {luxury_shopper: {factor: 10}} && {movie_goer: {factor: 80}})
```

you could do so using #send as such:

```
Observation.send('search', 'something', params)
```

Comment: That's a great solution! Thanks Ian. I'll award you the bounty in an hour when it lets me.

Comment: thank, arel. also occurs to me, you may want to have some safety checks in there for bad input data or sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if correctly understand your question, but if you need apply `&&` between arbitrary number of elements<del>, you may simply use [Enumerable#all?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) method, like</del>

```
filters = [{biz_trv:{factor: 10}}, {day_com:{factor:100}}, …]
Observation.search("something", boost_by: filters.all?)
```

**Update:**

```
filters = [{biz_trv:{factor: 12}}, {day_com:{factor:50}},
           {location:{factor:40}}]
Observation.search("something",
                   boost_by: filters.inject {|ac,e| ac && e})
```

Comment: `filters.all?` just returns `true`

Comment: @Arel I'm sorry, the question was probably not clear to me. Updating my answer with more generic solution which is equivalent to your example but works for arbitrary number of `boost_by` arguments and `&&` can by freely interchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want to use the same operator, you want to pass the output of your `map` to something that behaves like `inject`:

```
(params[:filter].map {|k,v| {k.to_sym => {factor:v}}}).inject() { |r,c| r && c }
```

Note: not tested!